# how to set date time field to null

Tags: c#, asp.net, interface

I am using .net 4.0. I have interface with date time fields like

```
 DateTime FromDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    DateTime ToDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

I want to set the value to this to null in my user interface like

```
IUser m_user = new User();
  m_user.FromDate = DBNull.value;
```

In shows error , like cannot convert null to datetime.

How to assign null to datetime?

Thanks ,
pooja

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do that, as DateTime can't get `null` value because it's [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx).

One way is changing your code to use [Nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead:

```
DateTime? FromDate
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Then it can be null:

```
m_user.FromDate = null;
```

Comment: That's a great answer. +1 for that

Answer (score 1):

For DateTime instead of null using DateTime.MinValue